# Extracting a set of characters/string from a character array

Tags: c

I am having trouble with my C programming and I would like some help in extracting a set of characters from a character array. The following below is in a character array:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:87.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 11
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8081/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
textbox=asd
```

I would like to extract "asd" from this entire chunk, how do I do this? Also, do note that the characters "asd" can be changed to any character or length. Please help..

Comment: Do you want the content copied, or simply point to the start of the string after `textbox=`?

Comment: i need the content after "textbox=" to be copied

Comment: Formatting note: you can force newlines by putting two space characters at the end of each line. But I find it easier just to convert the text into a code block.

Comment: ahh, i see!! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strstr` to search for `textbox=` and copy the rest of the string with `strdup`:

```
char *p = strstr(str, "textbox=");
if (p)
    char *t = strdup(p+sizeof("textbox=")-1);
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it worked!

Comment: Note that `strdup()` uses `malloc()` to create the returned string, that has to be passed to `free()` once you finish with it, or the memory will stay allocated and your program could run out of available memory.